# hibernate how to create inner join using hql

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have two entity classes mapped by onetomany :

```
@Entity
public class FilesInfo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String url;

    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="fileId")
    private Collection<FilesShare> filesShared = new ArrayList<FilesShare>();

    public Collection<FilesShare> getFilesShared() {
        return filesShared;
    }

    public void setFilesShared(Collection<FilesShare> filesShared) {
        this.filesShared = filesShared;
    }
 //getters & setters   
}
```

**the other one**

```
@Entity
public class FilesShare {
    private Integer id;
    private int userId;
    private int owner;
}
```

**the resultand tables are:**

```
mysql> desc filesshare;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userId | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| owner  | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fileId | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> desc filesinfo;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

now i am trying to perform inner join and get a list of type FilesInfo:

```
    @Override
        public List<FilesInfo> reqSharedFiles(FilesShare fs) {
            session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            List<FilesInfo> filesInfo = null;
            filesInfo=session.createQuery("select a.id, a.name, a.url from FilesInfo as a 
            inner join FilesShare as b on "+
            " a.id=b.fileId where b.userId= :userId and b.owner= :owner")
           .setInteger("userId",fs.getUserId()).setInteger("owner",fs.getOwner()).list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return filesInfo;
        }
```

**and i get this error**

> > Struts has detected an unhandled exception: Messages:
> >     org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.recover(Lantlr/RecognitionException;Lantlr/collections/impl/BitSet;)V
> >     File:   org/hibernate/hql/antlr/HqlBaseParser.java Line number:     1,802 app.dao.UploadDAOImpl.reqSharedFiles(UploadDAOImpl.java:79)
> >     < ------ this line pointing to filesInfo=session.createQuery("select

please please tell me where it is wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is issue with the version of hibernate and ANTLR jars that you are using. The recover method wasn't present in the ANTLR Parser class until version 2.7.6? If you are using an earlier version of ANTLR, such as 2.7.2, then you will get  problem.

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308555/i-need-help-with-this-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: one more thing i want to know is that, mapping is necessary in entity class to perform join operation? cant we do join on individual tables usin the hql?

Comment: hey i am getting this error now :   
unexpected token: on near line 1, column 86 [select a.id, a.name, a.url from app.domain.FilesInfo as a inner join FilesShare as b on a.id=b.fileId where b.userId= :userId and b.owner= :owner]

Comment: i think this is the syntax error in the query .It might be with on

Comment: sorry .I dont know the exact syntax for that