# No Such Method error in HQL

Tags: java, select, hql

I'm getting following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.recover(Lantlr/RecognitionException;Lantlr/collections/impl/BitSet;)V
    org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1173)
    org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:702)
    org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:296)
    org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:159)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:248)
```

when execute the following hql

```
select object(o),p.dateApply,p.reason,p.Approver from Person as o "+
                " com.jpa.entities.Application as p where o.id = p.nricNo and o.batchNumber= :batchNo
```

if i remove the following query

```
p.dateApply,p.reason,p.Approver
```

it's working just fine. The thing i want is to return value from both Person entities and Application entities.

Hope somebody can assist me as I'm new to HQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need help with this error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308555/i-need-help-with-this-error-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror)

Comment: Download the tool jfind from http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=114534 and search for the string "antlr/RecognitionException;Lantlr/collections/impl/BitSet" and see if it is found in multiple jars within your application. Then this is the root issue of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got either incompatible Hibernate-related JARs, or duplicates of some or all of those JARs.  Perhaps because you upgraded to a different version of Hibernate without deleting the old JARs (or something similar).

If different versions of the class com.my.MyClass are found in both lib1.jar and lib2.jar and the classloader loads MyClass from lib1.jar, but the "correct" MyClass (the one with the method the JRE is looking for) is found in lib2.jar, you'll experience exactly the problem you're seeing.